# Trying to get Get text out using selenium in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

this is email i want to show:

[image]

this is my Code :

```
getemail = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//b[contains(text(), '@')]").text
print(getemail)
```

and it showed nothing. Thank you for help!

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be easier to find that information by using the ID instead.

```
email = driver.find_element_by_id("email_ch_text").text
```

Comment: This is a question about python, why reference Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The xpath is not accurate. try this,

```
getemail = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//b/span[contains(text(), '@')]").text
print(getemail)
```